# Nothing happens when using method history.replaceState

Tags: azure, vue.js, azure-web-app-service, nuxt.js

I use azure app services for my nuxt application but when i use history.replaceState it doesnt replace the url. Running it on production on my own pc works fine but when I deploy it to azure it seems like its not doing anything. Maybe I did something wrong in my web.config?

(I also tried using this.$router.replace() which has the same results.)

```
selectBrand (brand) {
      const errors = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.error))
      history.replaceState({}, null, window.origin + '/error/'+brand);
      this.selectedBrand = brand
      this.errorList = this.error.filter(name => name.cBrandname.includes(brand))
    }
```

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/ for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This a interesting appearance. I try it in my .net app, it works fine. My suggestion is you can create a simple nuxt app, then publish again. If also show the error, it must be somrthing nedd to modify.
Generally, this kind of error will not occur.

Comment: Did you also publish it? Because locally it works but on the app service it doesnt (for me)

Comment: I create .netcore app and publish it in azure. I don't configure anything in web.config. I think it just relation with javascript. I will create nodejs app to check it later.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for raising the question and contributing to Stack Overflow.

Reiterating the answer from what Jason has mentioned as this should be solution for the problem you're facing .

Just create a sample Nuxt App and try to publish it again and see if it helps.